# How can I remove characters from a string after a particular character?

Tags: string, swift

Given a string, how do I truncate all characters following one particular character?

For example I have a url:

```
http://pics.v6.top.rbk.ru/v6_top_pics/resized/250xH/media/img/7/92/754435534528927.jpg"><div>Some text</div>"
```

I want to strip all characters after the `"`, including the `"` character.

Comment: U can use [Regular Expression](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBsQFjAAahUKEwjD96CCi53IAhVijXIKHUlYBRI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fmac%2Fdocumentation%2FFoundation%2FReference%2FNSRegularExpression_Class%2F&usg=AFQjCNGeS-aXT-D4919Jbg6o6CZknJ-Qgw&sig2=N0JSKhcsoyJVQoldj58jKA&bvm=bv.103627116,d.bGQ).

Answer (score 1):

```
extension String {
    mutating func stripFromCharacter(char:String) {
        let c = self.characters
        if let ix = c.indexOf("\"") {
            self = String(c.prefixUpTo(ix))
        }
    }
}
```

And here's how to use it:

```
var s = "http://pics.v6.top.rbk.ru/v6_top_pics/resized/250xH/media/img/7/92/754435534528927.jpg\"><div>Some text</div>"
s.stripFromCharacter("\"")
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the dumbest way to do it but it works.

```
let a = "http://pics.v6.top.rbk.ru/v6_top_pics/resized/250xH/media/img/7/92/754435534528927.jpg\"" + "><div>Some text</div>"
print(a)
var new = ""
for char in a.characters{
    if char == "\""{ break }
    new.append(char)
}

print(new)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you simply want to use [NSDataDetectors](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDataDetector_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?

E.G. something like:

```
let input = "http://pics.v6.top.rbk.ru/v6_top_pics/resized/250xH/media/img/7/92/754435534528927.jpg"><div>Some text</div>""
let detector = try! NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingType.Link.rawValue)
let matches = detector.matchesInString(input, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, input.characters.count))

for match in matches {
    let url = (input as NSString).substringWithRange(match.range)
    print(url)
}
```

More info can be found [in this HackingWithSwift blog post](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/strings/how-to-detect-a-url-in-a-string-using-nsdatadetector).